# Fazer com que crie barra de rolagem quando dois componentes se chocarem

Tags: css

Por exemplo, eu tenho duas divs na pagina, e elas são definidas por width e height, porem quando elas se chocarem eu gostaria que eu invés de uma delas descer ou subir, simplesmente aparecer uma barra de rolagem.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo utilizando `box-flex`, não sei atende ao seu caso, mas segue abaixo:

```css
.pagina {
  overflow: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}
.esquerda {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.direita {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagina">
  <div class="esquerda">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="direita">
    b
  </div>
</div>
```